# Watcher batch file for .txt cloning/reseting/modification

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that works something like a watcher, here is what I am trying to do:

- The batch keeps monitoring a `.txt` file for any modification.
- Once the file has been modified by any reason, the batch file proceeds with its function.
- The function can vary, either change/replace/delete a line of text inside the file or replace the actual `.txt` file with a previous clone of it.
- After this it keeps monitoring, the cycle repeats itself to prevent the file from being modified.

I do not understand anything of batch, I have tried to find guides and ways of doing it but I am really confused so if anyone could help me with this (a guide explaining how to or the actual final batch) I would be very grateful.

Thank you for your time and patience!

Comment: looks a lot like a suspicious activity. Why do you want to do such active prevention of a file from being modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Batch file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) article on Wikipedia will give you enough information to start understanding batch files.

There is a basic example with explanation that will be helpful getting started with running batch file.

Also take a look at the resources mentioned at the [Stack Overflow Batch tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch/info)

Once you know how to write batch files, look for commands that you will require to complete your task.